# Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Migrei o site da locaweb para a hostgator e o php estão em versões diferentes. Agora preciso usar mysqli. Ja arrumei o /public_html/.../mysql.php. Agora esse arquivo: /home3/.../PHPFrodo.class.php está com esse erro.

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home3/.../PHPFrodo.class.php on line 1951
```

Pelo que entendi, é preciso passar uma conexão como 1º parametro, mas não sei como fazer.

Parte do código da linha 1951:

```
public function post2Query( $arr2query )
{
    try
    {
        if ( !is_array( $arr2query ) || empty( $arr2query ) )
        {
            throw new Exception( 'post2query: O paramêtro não é um array ou está vazio!' );
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ( $arr2query as $key => $value )
            {
                $value = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->dbase, $value); // <== linha 1951
                $this->post_fields[] = trim( "$key" );
                $this->post_values[] = trim( "$value" );
                //$this->post_values[] = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $value);
            }
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception $e )
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Acredito que o `$this->dbase` está sendo declarado no código abaixo.
O erro acontece ao tentar incluir informações via dashboard.

```
public function database( $dbase = 'default' )
    {
        try
        {
            if ( $dbase != null )
            {
                $this->dbase = $dbase;
            }
            if ( file_exists( DATABASEDIR . 'database.conf.php' ) )
            {
                include DATABASEDIR . 'database.conf.php';
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception( "database: Arquivo de configuração do banco inexistente!" );
            }
            if ( !isset( $databases["$this->dbase"] ) )
            {
                throw new Exception( "database: banco [$this->dbase] não configurado em " . DATABASEDIR . "database.conf.php" );
            }
            //conexao adapters
            $this->adapter( $databases[$this->dbase]['driver'] );
            $this->objBanco = new $this->adapter( $databases[$this->dbase] );
            $this->dbname = $databases[$this->dbase]['dbname'];
            $this->sgbd = $databases[$this->dbase]['driver'];
        }
        catch ( Exception $e )
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Qual o valor de `$this->dbase`?

Comment: Editei o post, @AndersonCarlosWoss, seria essa parte? Na mesma pasta existe um arquivo chamado Conexao.class.php. Que, pelo que entendi, faz uma conexão com o BD, será que tenho que chamar uma variavel de conexão com o BD desse arquivo? O Erro está acontecendo ao tentar incluir dados via dashboard/admin.

Comment: A função que você está utilizando espera uma instância de `mysqli`; o que você está passando é uma *string* com a configuração de acesso.